# JavaScript - Getting a file from url to byte array

Tags: javascript, arrays, byte

I have a large file (several gigs) that is accessible via URL that I need to pass to a Java-based web service that expects a `byte[]` array.

I have no problem calling the web services (basically it's using JSON objects to pass to a Java file).

I'm just not sure of:

a) How to use JavaScript to get from a URL

and

b) How to convert that into a binary format that could be passed to a `byte[]` in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the URL on the same domain? Either way, you won't be able to do that in JS; Javascript cannot stream.

Comment: The URL is on the same domain as where the Javascript is running, but not the Java web service.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX can be used, but expects data in UTF-8. so you'd have to convert your bit stream to an encoding scheme such as Base64 first.